# Caesar cipher not functioning, not sure what's wrong with it

Tags: python, string, encryption, caesar-cipher

I need to create a simple Caesar cipher encoder/decoder and im not sure the best way to do it, strings? lists? loops?

```
Word = input("What do you want to decode")
Shift = input("What do you want the shift to be?") 
alphabet = ["A","B", "C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N",
            "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

for letters in Word:
    if letters == [alphabet.index(letters)]:
        print [alphabet.index(letters + Shift)]       

for a in alphabet:
    if a == letters:
        print (letters+(alphabet.index(letters)))
```

As you can tell I tried `for` loops to separate list items and compare but it didn't work so I'm not sure how to proceed, cannot use the `translate` or `order` function.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with a single `for` loop, I would suggest `for letter in Word:`. Your `if` statement doesn't really fit and you seem to be using `[]` a lot more than you need to. To get the `n`th letter in the alphabet you can use `alphabet[n]`. To get the position of the letter `letter` in the alphabet, you can use `alphabet.index(letter)`. Combining these two will get you pretty close. What happens when you shift "Z"?

Comment: This code has obvious indentation errors.  Please fix.

Comment: Also, is B missing from the alphabet on purpose?

Comment: `print [alphabet.index(letters + Shift)]` is incorrect in Python 3 because `print` is a function.

Answer (score 0):

- Your `alphabet` list is missing at least one letter, so that might mess with your results.  I suggest using `string.ascii_uppercase` instead.
- In the statement `if letters == [alphabet.index(letters)]` you're mixing up the letter (`letters` -- this actually is just one letter!) with the `index` of the letter in `alphabet`; it's impossible for them to *ever* be the same since one is a string and another is an int.  You don't need to loop to find the index anyway; the `index` function does that for you.
- Make sure to "wrap" the shift around the end of the alphabet!  The mod (`%`) operator is an easy way to do that.
- Careful of characters that aren't in `alphabet` at all.

```
import string

word = input("What do you want to decode? ").upper()
shift = int(input("What do you want the shift to be? "))
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase

print(''.join(
    alphabet[
        (alphabet.index(c) + shift) % len(alphabet)
    ] if c in alphabet else c for c in word
))
```

```
What do you want to decode? ZEBRA STRIPES
What do you want the shift to be? 12
LQNDM EFDUBQE
```

Comment: This is correct and idiomatic pythonic but seems a far above the level of OP. I'd suggest a simple loop that accumulates output by appending to a string and maybe an `if` that handles the wrapping logic.

Answer (score 0):

use this loop

```
import string
Word = input("What do you want to decode")
Shift = input("What do you want the shift to be?") 
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
ouput = ""
for i in Word:
    if i.upper() in alphabet:
        if alphabet.find(i.upper())+int(Shift)>25:
            ouput += alphabet[alphabet.find(i.upper())+int(Shift)-25]
        else:
            ouput += alphabet[alphabet.find(i.upper())+int(Shift)]
    else:
        ouput+=i 
print(ouput)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input("What do you want to decode ")
shift = input("What do you want the shift to be? ")

alphabet = ["A","B", "C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N",
            "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

def caesar_encrypt(word: str, shift: int):
    return ''.join(alphabet[(alphabet.index(char) + shift) % len(alphabet)]
                   if char in alphabet else char for char in word)

def caesar_decript(word: str, shift: int):
    return caesar_encrypt(word, 26-shift)

word = word.upper()
shift = int(shift)

encrypted_word = caesar_encrypt(word, shift)
print(encrypted_word)

decripted_word = caesar_decript(encrypted_word, shift)
print(decripted_word)
```